# Refresh PHP that grabs Co-Ords for google maps API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am using the google maps API to show the last position a form was submitted to my site. So I am pulling the lon and lat values from a php file as variables but I need the script to refresh every 5 seconds so that the maps marker updates without page reload.

Here is the google api script:

```
    <script>

      function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng<?php 
require($DOCUMENT_ROOT . "php_includes/mobile_loc.php");

?>;
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Last Scan'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

And here is the php file:

```
    <?php 
include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php"); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM patdub ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(Timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$lon = $row['Lon'];
$lat = $row['Lat'];

echo "($lat, $lon)";

?>
```

Any ideas? I've tried different AJAX methods but just can't seem to figure it out!

Edit: The line of code below is basically the bit I need to refresh every 5 seconds but without any div tags or anything because that interferes with the google api script..

```
<?php require($DOCUMENT_ROOT . "php_includes/mobile_loc.php"); ?>;
```

Comment: There is no AJAX in your code. You need AJAX. Saying "I've tried different AJAX methods" and then not showing any is not very useful for diagnostics of why it doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to call load the file your PHP script is in, assuming that it is in it's own file, you would do that like so and you can then update your DOM using the return from the AJAX call.
You would wrap the AJAX call in a javascript loop such as setInterval() like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "php_script.php"
    }).done(function(return) {
        console.log(return);
    });
, 5000);
```

To call it every 5 seconds.

To incorportate it with your Google function (I have no knowledge of google maps so this may not be 100% accurate):

```
<script>

    function initialize(myLatlng) {
        myLatlng = myLatlng || new google.maps.LatLng<?php require($DOCUMENT_ROOT . "php_includes/mobile_loc.php");?>;
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatlng
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Last Scan'
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax(function() {
            url: 'php_script.php'
        }.done(function(response) {
            var latlong = response;
            initialize(latLong)
        });
    }, 5000)

</script>
```

Comment: So I would put that javascript loop before the google api script? or within a different script tag? and thanks for the reply this is very helpful!

Comment: I would put it after the google API script and then, when you get a return from the PHP function, call the Google API function and pass the data through. I will edit my answer to explain this now.

Comment: Yeah that didn't work, once I added that code there is no map showing at all, I even tried changing the interval to 30 seconds and changing the response variable to "var myLatlong" but still nothing :(

Comment: Okay, before I edit the answer, try changing your first map call to: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(null));`. May not work, but just a theory.

Comment: No that didn't work either :( I noticed that the variable is actually "myLatlng" though that might be the problem but I tried it with and without the new DOM listener but still no joy! I'm sure the solution is very simple..

Comment: If you split it into two different functions then it will work, have your initialize function how it was originally and have another function, `refresh` for example, which gets the individual value of lat and long from the PHP script, using split would probably be best, and then plug those value into the funciton.